# Seeking Berlin groundwater shapefiles

Tags: data, germany

I would like to know if any of you has shapefiles of Berlin?

I have been using https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/index.jsp but it doesn't allow the layers in shapefile format and also https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/search?sort=-modified but I can't find the shapefile of Groundwater.

I am working on my thesis project and need this information.

Comment: If you need this for your thesis, you can contact Landesamt für Umwelt Brandenburg/Berlin. If you seek opendata, I'd try https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to contact them.